# Python Selenium: Having trouble fixing NoSuchElementException for a specific button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to press a button with selenium in python. I am not able to locate it with xpath or css selector.

For the rest of the things in the script I have been using xpath and it works fine, but this button's xpath seems to be relative each time I open it. Therefore I have tried to access is with the css selector.

The element I am trying to access looks like this:

```
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Opret AnnonceAgent</button>
```

The css selector from inspect in chrome:

```
#\35 d167939-adc2-0901-34ea-406e6c26e1ab > div.modal-footer > div > button.btn.btn-primary.pull-right
```

Let me know if I should post more html.

I have tried many stack oveflow questions, and tried many variatiosn of the css selector, like putting it as:

- `driver.find_element_by_class_name('#\35 d167939-adc2-0901-34ea-406e6c26e1ab.div.modal-footer.div.button.btn.btn-primary.pull-rightdiv.button.btn.btn-primary-pull-right').click()`
- `driver.find_element_by_class_name('div.button.btn.btn-primary-pull-right').click()`
- `driver.find_element_by_class_name('button.btn.btn-primary-pull-right').click()`
- `driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn.btn-primary-pull-right').click()`
- `driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-primary-pull-right').click()`

I have also tried a sleep timer.

The button is in a window that opens when you press the previous button, with the background greyed out, if that helps. [Picture](https://imgur.com/mz15BIW).

```
# This opens up the window in which to press the next button (works fine)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/section/div[2]/button')
button.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
time.sleep(5)
# This is what doesn't work
driver.find_element_by_class_name('button.btn.btn-primary-pull-right').click()
```

I expect for the program to press the button and it doesn't, it just sits there.

Comment: Try that see if it works `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn.btn-primary.pull-right').click()`

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work. I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`, assuming because it's element[s] - was that intentional?

Comment: it was typo.try again `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn.btn-primary.pull-right').click()`

Comment: Doesn't work, I get `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Can you check if there any frame which blocking to locate the button?

Comment: If it is public link can you share the url to check what’s wrong there?

Comment: It is not, as you have to be logged in. Check this out though - you can see how it is inside another div, is that something i should be accounting for? [Picture](https://imgur.com/vl2aDTq). Edit: I've highlited the button and the thing it's inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is within a *Modal Dialog Box*, so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-primary.pull-right[data-dismiss='modal']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary pull-right' and @data-dismiss='modal'][text()='Opret AnnonceAgent']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`class_name` recives one class as parameter, but you are using `css` syntax as locator.

With `css_selector`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn.btn-primary-pull-right')
```

Which means `<button>` tag with 2 classes, `btn` and `btn-primary-pull-right`

With `class_name`

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-primary-pull-right')
```

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen Please elaborate. What exactly happened?

Comment: Right, sorry! I got the same exception, the `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"btn-primary-pull-right"}`, and similarly for the other one.

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen Try adding [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits). You should also check if the button is in `<iframe>`

Comment: thanks, I've tried both of these already (`time.sleep(t)` as well as in the thread @KajulKundu)

Answer (score 0):

My guess was right.There was an `iframe` which stopping to access the element.You have to switch to `iframe` first to access the `button` element.Try now with following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

#WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//iframe[starts-with(@id,"rdr_")]')))
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//iframe[@id="qualaroo_dnt_frame"]')))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn.btn-primary').click()
```

Comment: Are you able to make this word? When I implement it, I get a `TimeoutException`.

Comment: well do one thing  try this `WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//iframe[@id="qualaroo_dnt_frame"]')))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn.btn-primary').click()`

Comment: Hm, for that one I get a `NoSuchElementException` for the button again.

Comment: can you do one thing instead of image can you share the html so that i can copy entire html and test on my laptop whats wrong?

Comment: Is the same html you are looking for?I can't find any iframe here when i see the html however when you posted image it was showing iframe?

Comment: Ah, right sorry, this is the page source, but the stuff we are working with is rendered after the javascript. Is there a way for me to get the html with selenium so I can send i to you?

Comment: Once you reach the page press F12 on chrome and get the html